# Cannot access firebase from within an electron app

Tags: firebase, ember.js, electron, emberfire

Trying to build an Electron app using `ember-electron` and am trying to use `emberfire` to communicate with Firebase. Everything runs fine when running as a web app with `ember s` but when launching as an Electron app I get nothing but errors like this:

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load https://www.googleapis.com/identitytoolkit/v3/relyingparty/signupNewUser?key=AIzaSyBYyuJ-1E3ufujlzdKhj8gE9I6QH8TreJE. Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'serve://dist' is therefore not allowed access. The response had HTTP status code 404.
```

Is this a known problem or does anyone know a way around this? Unfortunately cannot simply add `serve://dist` to the list of authorized domains as Google doesn't consider it a valid domain name.

**Update**: I would still love to know if anyone has a possible workaround but I found a tool called Nativefier (https://github.com/jiahaog/nativefier) which works for my purposes. Since I am simultaneously developing a web app and a desktop app, once the web app is being hosted, can use nativefier to build the desktop app

Answer (score 0):

I didn't try with electron, but played with node-webkit. Many problems related to origin can be solved by running local web-server: in main script run a web-server using express which serves your app. This is piece of code that I use to start local server:

```
let express = require('express');
let http = require('http');
let app = express();
app.use('/', express.static('dist'));
let server = http.createServer(app);
let port = 9000;
let maxPort = 50000;
server.on('error', function (e) {
    if (port < maxPort) {
        server.listen(++port);
    } else {
        alert('Your system has no free ports to start a web-server, which is needed for this app to work');
        window.nw.Window.get().close();
    }
});
server.on('listening', function () {
    location = 'http://localhost:' + port + '/index.html';
});
server.listen(port);
```

I think that something similar should work for electron, too